# В какой кодировке работать с китайским языком? Python

Tags: python, кодировка

Час добрый
Возникла необходимость работать с китайским языком, но не знаю в какой кодировке сохранять китайский текст в txt
Пример текста и сайта:

```
M9040#P60 迪奥官网同款对格印花系列衬衣 尺码M-XXL28
尺寸表
M；胸围110 后中衣长73.5 袖长20 肩宽49
L； 胸围114 后中衣长75 袖长21 肩宽50
XL; 胸围118 后中衣长76.5 袖长22 肩宽51
XXL 胸围122 后中衣长78 袖长23 肩宽52
尺寸为手工测量，误差2-3cm属正常情况

Сайт: https://guangzhouchaopaishengchenshang.x.yupoo.com/albums/112690191?uid=1
```

Каким способом обработать данный текст для записи в txt?
Заранее благодарю за ответы
EDITED
Добавляю код с местом сохранения описания в файл:

```
            description_field = soup.find('div', class_='showalbumheader__gallerysubtitle htmlwrap__main')
            description_info = description_field.text
            description_info = description_info.encode().decode('utf8')
            print(f'[INFO] Save description album file')
            with open(f'{path_save}/description.txt', 'w', errors='ignore') as desc:
                desc.write(description_info)
```

При помощи bs4 вытаскиваю описание и пытаюсь сохранить его в txt. Т.к. раньше китайский текст не требовался, то просто пропускал его при помощи игнорирования ошибочных элементов для записи, но сейчас требуются и они. В данном варианте китайские символы не сохраняются

Comment: Чем не устраивает utf-8?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич В каком формате это оформить? К переменной с текстом применить  .encode().decode('utf8'). И к файлу прописать encoding='utf8' ?

Comment: Вы хотите в текстовый файл сохранять? Если да, то при его открытии просто указываете параметр encoding='utf-8'. C базами данных несколько сложнее. Но вообще, если что то идёт не так как ожидалось - надо бы код, который у Вас не работает "из коробки".

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Обновил с добавлением кода, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Ваш код под linux должен работать без проблем. Под windows обязательно укажите encoding в параметрах open

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич спасибо, проверю

Comment: Если под Windows установка `encoding='utf-8'` не поможет, попробуйте `encoding='utf-8-sig'`